# optimal staff cost for project

Tags: excel, projection, forecasting

I have an IT desktop equipment move project that requires hiring outside help to perform the moves themselves.

I need to know what is the optimal amount of staff to hire, given that I know:
Variables:
- Number of moves
- Number of IT staff

Constants (some number obfuscated for contractual reasons)
- Avg amount of time per move: 30 minutes
- Price per staff: X$ per hour
- Minimal cost: Y Hours

The optimal head count would be minimal cost and minimal effort per IT staff.

Is there a tool where I can model this out and have the tool spit out the answer?

Right now I have and excel sheet where I manually change the number of technicians until I get the result I'm looking for. This is fine for smaller moves, but as the number grows, so does the manual work. I tried to look into projections with Excel, but I'm not proficient enough.

Comment: This is non-programming question and furthermore asking us to recommend or find a tool etc. is explicitly off-topic here. This problem and it's solution belongs to [Project Management (beta) Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might benefit from looking into the Excel Solver add-in:

http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/solver.html